# Sum the json array based on the occurance of the string in the key and store it in the separate json array with the string and its count

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON array which consists data as follows:

```
var teamDetails=[ 
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 5},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Business", "count" : 1,},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Internet Services", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 6},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 1} 
];
```

So I need to sum the count based on the ptype like Content Server = 3 times, Search Engines = 12 times and so on followed for the other data. The data is not static since I work on rest services so it would change but the format of the data is the same. The code should be dynamic to work on any change in ptype data.

Comment: so what you  tried?

Comment: that's why I posted I'm not able to figure it out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to resolve this. here is what it should look like

```
var data = teamDetails.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const index = prev.findIndex(a => a.pType === curr.pType)
  if (index !== -1) {
    prev[index].count = prev[index].count + curr.count;
  } else {
  prev.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
}, [])
```

```js
var teamDetails = [{
    "pType": "Search Engines",
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "pType": "Content Server",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pType": "Content Server",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pType": "Search Engines",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pType": "Business",
    "count": 1,
  },
  {
    "pType": "Content Server",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pType": "Internet Services",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pType": "Search Engines",
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "pType": "Search Engines",
    "count": 1
  }
];

var data = teamDetails.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const index = prev.findIndex(a => a.pType === curr.pType)
  if (index !== -1) {
    prev[index].count = prev[index].count + curr.count;
  } else {
  prev.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
}, [])
console.log(data);
```